# Sequelize filter by combination of fields

Tags: sql-server, filter, sequelize.js

I have an address table which has fields: `{AddressLine1, City, State, Zip}`

I want to filter by the combination of these fields so that the results are returned only when the following condition matches:

searchKeyword is a subset of (AddressLine1 + " " + City + ", " + state + " " + zip)

```
addressLine1 = 2384  River Road
city = Colorado springs
state = CO
zip = 80918
desired combination = 2384  River Road Colorado springs, CO 80918
return record if the searchKeyword is subset of desired combination. 
e.g.["River Road Colorado", "CO 80918", "springs, CO"]
sql wise => desiredCombination like '%searchKeyword%'
```

I looked into the sequelize docs and got hold of [complex filtering](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#complex-filtering-or-not-queries) using `[Op.or] [Op.and]` and other operators.

I also looked at [Complex where clauses at the top-level](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html)

But I could not find anything relevant about what I want to do in the docs.

What I currently have:

```
model.findAll({
    where: { addressLine1: { [Op.like]: `%${searchKeyword}%` } }
})
```

*I don't want to use raw queries if possible. Thanks.*

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a where clause as follows -

```
where: {
      [op.and]: [Sequelize.literal('concat (addressLine1,city,state,zip) LIKE ${searchKeyword} )')]
    },
```

Hope it helps!